# AppendText rather than Text to textbox1: avoiding cross thread operation

Tags: c#, multithreading, appendtext

I'm using this to write text back into `textbox1`, and it works correctly to avoid cross thread operation, but...  I only receive a single line of output from it.  Any idea how I can do more of an `AppendText` call rather than a basic text call?

```
  private void SetText(string text)
    {
        // InvokeRequired required compares the thread ID of the
        // calling thread to the thread ID of the creating thread.
        // If these threads are different, it returns true.
        if (this.textBox1.InvokeRequired)
        {
            SetTextCallback d = new SetTextCallback(SetText);
            this.Invoke(d, new object[] { text });
        }
        else
        {
            this.textBox1.Text = text;
        }
    }
```

Comment: There is also literally an AppendText() method: `this.textBox1.AppendText(text);`

Comment: Thanks, this actually works better for my purpose, since the textbox still initiates the autoscroll with this method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 private void SetText(string text)
 {
    // InvokeRequired required compares the thread ID of the
     // calling thread to the thread ID of the creating thread.
      // If these threads are different, it returns true.
    if (this.textBox1.InvokeRequired)
      {
        SetTextCallback d = new SetTextCallback(SetText);
        this.Invoke(d, new object[] { text });
     }
    else
     {
         //append  text  like  this  
         this.textBox1.Text += text;
     }
}
```